Static field cannot be referenced from a non static context
I have a batch class and some static variables which I am initializing in the constructor. Getting the error: Static field cannot be referenced from a non static context. This error is shown from inside the constructor.
Below is the code:
public class BatchTestClone implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    public static DateTime testDate;
    public static String status;
    public BatchTestClone(DateTime testDate, String status) {
        this.testDate= testDate;
        this.status= status;

    }
}

How can this be resolved?

By removing the static keyword from your two class variables, or changing this.<variable name> to BatchTestClone.<variable name> in your constructor.
Either will work, but I'd suggest the "remove the static keyword" approach.
Static variables are tied to the lifetime of the transaction, and wouldn't get "saved" (so to speak) when Salesforce would run the start()/execute()/finish() methods.
Class-level "instance variables", however, do get "saved" and would be available in the start()/execute()/finish() methods.
Also, the general difference between static and instance methods and variables is:

static members are referenced using the class name (e.g. MyClass.theNiceNumberStatic), and are the same for everything that uses it
instance members need an instance of a class to reference them (e.g. MyClass myInstance = new MyClass(); myInstance.startDate = Date.today();) and can be different between different instances of the class


These variables act as a configuration which is consistent across all executions of the batch class. Would this makes sense to keep static?

@coder123 No, for the reason I outlined in my answer (static variables don't get "saved" like that for batch classes). That's why I suggest removing the static keyword.

To make them persistent during entire run - it makes sense to use Database.Stateful interface - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm / Using State in Batch Apex

@kurunve If you don't need those variables to change, then Stateful isn't necessary. Instance variables that are set before passing the instance into Database.executeBatch() (via constructor or otherwise) get serialized and are available in start/finish and in all individual runs of execute().
